# Python 3.5. Найти и вывести текст, заключённый в кавычках: " "

Tags: python

Имею огромную, постоянно изменяющуюся стену текста, типа:

```
jdgfhksdfgflsdhjflsdhflsdjhfljk, "nujnoe": "123123", hsdfgflsdHLFhsdnlfhsD, "nenujnoe": "123124", gnojngjofkhgbhdlkfjghdlfj...
```

(взято из головы). Текст постоянно меняется, кроме названия "переменной"(nujnoe). Мне нужно вывести на экран то, что находится в кавычках после слова "nujnoe".

Надеюсь, правильно донёс вопрос, надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Регулярное выражение?

Comment: А можно текст взятый НЕ из головы? Есть подозрение, что это json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если строка текста не настолько огромна, чтобы ее можно было обработать при помощи RegEx, то можно так:

```
import re

found = re.findall(r'"nujnoe":\s*"([^\"]*)"', s)
```

Это найдет все вхождения. Например:

```
In [159]: s = 'jdg, "nujnoe": "123", hsd, "nenujnoe": "098", aaa, "nujnoe": "56789", bbb'

In [160]: found = re.findall(r'"nujnoe":\s*"([^\"]*)"', s)

In [161]: found
Out[161]: ['123', '56789']
```

---

Если же это JSON, то можно его распарсить:

```
In [170]: s = '{"jdg":"xxx", "nujnoe": "123", "nenujnoe": "098", "nujno": "56789"}'

In [171]: import json

In [172]: dct = json.loads(s)

In [173]: dct.get('nujnoe')
Out[173]: '123'
```

если все остальное не интересует, то можно выбрать только нужную переменную:

```
In [174]: val = json.loads(s).get('nujnoe')

In [175]: val
Out[175]: '123'
```

Если нужна потоковая обработка JSON, то стоит обратить внимание на [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson)